# Hom and Injective envelope

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, injective-module

let $R$ be Noetherian ring and $m$ , $n$ are maximal ideals of $R$ s.t. $m\neq n$.
can I say that
‎$$Hom_R(E_R(R/m),E_R(R/n))=0?$$
why?

Comment: Yes. The radical of the annihilator of any element of $E(R/m)$ for a maximal ideal $m$ is $m$.